# How to use XSL to create HTML attributes?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Why is using XML data to style HTML tags illegal? For example:

```
<li style="width:<xsl:value-of select="width"/>px">
```

Why can't I do this? Are there any alternative methods out there?

Comment: I like your nickname! :)

Comment: YES!! AFTER HALF A YEAR OF USING SO SOMEBODY NOTICES!!!!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Why can't I do this?
>
> ```
> <li style="width:<xsl:value-of select="width"/>px">
> ```

Because XSL is XML *itself*. And this is anything… but not XML.

You mean an [Attribute Value Template](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#attribute-value-templates):

```
<li style="width:{width}px">
```

or the explicit form, for more complex expressions:

```
<li>
  <xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="some[condition = 'is met']">thisValue</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>thatValue</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</li>
```

or dynamic attribute names (note that attribute value template in the name):

```
<li>
  <xsl:attribute name="{$attrName}">someValue</xsl:attribute>
</li>
```

Additional note: Attributes must be created *before* all other child nodes. In other words, keep `<xsl:attribute>` at the top.

Comment: Yes, I've tried something like this. However xsl:attribute must be a child of <xsl:stylesheet> meaning the last block of code given would be invalid?

Comment: @stockoverflow: xsl:attribute does not have to be a child of xsl:stylesheet. Why do you think that?

Comment: I've been trying to add an id property to a <div> element, but ALL of my html attributes are being removed except for class and href as far as I can tell. Any clue why that might be happening?

Comment: @robert.bo.roth I'm not sure this is this related to this thread. Instead of posting this without context to some unrelated comments section, it's better to ask this as a new question, with relevant sample code.

Comment: I posted a question already (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529202/xsl-is-ignoring-some-of-my-attributes), I just thought it might be related to this, since I'm having issues with any attributes showing up altogether, dynamic or not.

Answer (score 9):

Your original xsl is not well formed as you can't have the xsl tag inside another node.

I think you need to use xsl:attribute as follows:

```
<li>
  <xsl:attribute name="style">
     width:<xsl:value-of select="width"/>px;
  </xsl:attribute>
</li>
```

Comment: Tomalak's solution uses concat which is pretty handy, though.

Comment: One issue with this solution in the general case however- your attribute value will actually have a significant amount of whitespace before the `width:` text, as the whitespace used to format it is included as part of the text. HTML won't care about that though, but for some use cases it might be important.

Comment: I think it's much cleaner and readable to do : <li style="width:{width}px"> (for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing to an xml-tag

```
XML: <width>640</width>
XSLT: <li style="width:{width}px">
```

If you are referencing to an xml-tag-attribute:

```
XML: <box width="640" height="480">...</box>
XSLT: 
<xsl:for-each select="box">
  <li style="width:{@width}px; height:{@height}px;">
</xsl:for-each>
```