# xsl transform of my xml sitemap is not working using php

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt, sitemap

I have a simple sitemap.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>"home page link"/</loc>
        <title>East Randolph Cabinet Shop</title>
        <level>level-1</level>
    </url>
    .
    .
    .
    </urlset>
```

Then I have my sitemap.xsl file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <h2>Sitemap</h2>
     <ul>
     <xsl:for-each select="urlset/url">
      <li class="&lt;xsl:value-of select=&quot;level&quot;/&gt;"><a href="&lt;xsl:value-of select=&quot;loc&quot;/&gt;"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a></li>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then I have code in my sitemap.php file that should transform the xml file with the xsl file and then echo the results:

```
<div id="content">
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('sitemap.xml');
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('sitemap.xsl');
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
?>

</div>
```

When I direct my browser to the sitemap.php file all that is echoed is up until the Sitemap heading `<h2>Sitemap</h2>`. I'm very new to xsl so excuse my ignorance, but this looks like to me that something is wrong with my xsl for-each statement. Am I correct? I'm just stuck with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to use XSL to create HTML attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5090554/2261774) - If you need pointers: `<li class="&lt;xsl:value-of select=&quot;level&quot;/&gt;">` this *does not work*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems with your XSL file.

1. You don't use the correct XML namespace for sitemap files.
2. You don't know about attribute value templates.

Something like the following should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <h2>Sitemap</h2>
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="sm:urlset/sm:url">
            <li class="{sm:level}">
                <a href="{sm:loc}"><xsl:value-of select="sm:title"/></a>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the `sm` prefix for the sitemap XML namespace and the attribute value templates.

Comment: Thanks nwellnhof. This worked exactly as plan. Like a charm...much appreciated